# How do I get my Samsung S5 to re-connect to my PC and Android Studio? Used to work but stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I had my `Samsung S5` mini connected with Android Studio and was working with the setup for more than 4 months. Two days ago it suddenly stopped working. The device stopped showing on the device chooser. On closer look it appears that even Windows won't Recognition  the device. When connected it just charges.

Things I have already tried.

1. Connected another Samsung S5 using the same cable successfully.
2. Restarted both PC and mobile several times.
3. Played with Developer options -> USB Debugging. Restarted.
4. Tried *#0808# and undo/redo settings to MTP + ADB. Rebooted.
5. Tried another USB cable (original that came with Samsung). Same result.
6. Re-scanned the hardware from Windows -> Device Manager. No change. Also looked for anomalies or warning icons but could not find any issue.
7. Tried connecting to the other USB ports. Also tried another phone on the same port and that works.

I have already searched for an answer and tried almost all suggestions but could not get it to work.

Was someone able to fix a similar issue?
Anything else I can try?
Could this be a hardware issue and not just software? Anything to do with USB port on the mobile device?

This is how the developer options look in my phone's settings

[Click here for see Developer Options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hQVL.jpg)

[Click here for see USB Settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g6FV.jpg)

[Click here for see Notification panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM5Ke.jpg)

Here is Device Manager view on my PC. I have 2 phones connected to my PC but it shows only one. This question is about the one that is not showing.

[Click here for see Device Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuTqw.jpg)

**SOLVED**
See my answer in the comments section

Comment: do you change USB option from charging to USB-Debugging??

Comment: did you tried connecting it as camera ?

Comment: @ViratPuar What do you mean USB Option? I have enabled USB Debugging from Developer Options. That's what I did 4 months ago as well. Is there another place I should look at?

Comment: @ashutiwari4 How to do that? Note that when I connect the USB cable to my phone I do not get any option on Windows. Normally I get action chooser (reinforced by the sound when you connect a new device) but when I connect this phone its just nothing. The phone simple starts charging.

Comment: check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/). Did you tried with other usb ? it may be possible that your USB is having some problem.

Comment: share a screenshot of your device manger!

Comment: @dmSherazi added the screenshots. Thanks

Comment: @ashutiwari4 Yes I tried other ports and also tried other Samsung phone on the same port and that works (Updated my question with the details.)

Comment: @ashutiwari4 Also read the article but not sure how to get to the "UBS Computer Connection" settings screen. Some articles has suggested that on the Storage page but i don't see it there.

Comment: Check if USB debugging is on also try to change the USB cable for once.

Comment: @ashutiwari4 Yes the USB debugging is on and I have changed the cable as well. (Attached the image to the question)
[Click here for see Developer Options image][1]

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the USB/ADB drivers got uninstalled. Check your [device manager](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm). If you find an entry that requires drivers with a yellow alert/warning icon, something similar to the image below but not exactly this.

[image: Device manager]

If that is the case you need to install the appropriate USB/ADB driver for the device. Once driver is installed you can view the device in Android studio.

Comment: Thanks. I checked my device manager already but it does not show any driver issues. I also re scanned for hardware changes. Updated my question with a screenshot of how my device manager looks like. I have 2 phones connected to my PC. One of them shows but the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my phone. In the end I brought a brand new USB cable, switched my phone completely on and off and then made sure that USB debugging was enabled on the phone. Then the phone was recognised by my pc and in android studio.

Comment: Thanks but like I mentioned in my questions I have already tried changing the cable and restarting

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually found the problem and fixed it for me. I do not know the root cause but my phone works now with the same cable and without changing any other settings. 
I noticed that the camera on my phone also stopped working. I tried restarting the phone on safe mode, hard reboot the phone, force stopped the camera app, cleared the cache and cleared data but none of this fixed it. 
I then uninstalled some of the apps that i knew were using camera like snapchat but even that did not fix it. 
I eventually opened the phone and took the SD card out. Restarted the phone and viola.
Connected the phone to USB cable and connects as expected.